# String to a unique pointer array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c++11, smart-pointers

I'm trying to convert a string to a unique_ptr array in c++ but while using strcpy(), I'm getting an error, Here's what I did

```
int arraysize{0},i{0};
std::string word; 

std::cout<<"Input size of array: ";
std::cin>>arraysize;
std::cin.get();
std::unique_ptr<char[]>ch_array(new char[arraysize]);

std::cout<<"Input a word: ";
getline (std::cin, word);
strcpy(ch_array,word);
```

I'm want to get a word and convert it into a character array to check if it's a palindrome or not.
Also I only need to use a character array made using smart pointers because i'm a beginner in c++ and i'm trying to practice smart pointers.

Error:q3.cpp: In function 'int main()':
q3.cpp:17:22: error: cannot convert 'std::unique_ptr' to 'char*' for argument '1' to 'char* strcpy(char*, const char*)'
  strcpy(ch_array,word);

Any suggestions would be helpful.
thanks!

Comment: 1. Please tag the question with the language. 2. Please add the exact error message. 3. Explain why you need to do this

Comment: @UnholySheep Thanks! updated.

Comment: As the error states, `strcpy` doesn't accept these types. You'd need to get access to the underlying pointers/arrays. However there shouldn't be any need for this, you can just work directly with the `std::string`

Comment: You can use `strcpy( ch_array.get(), word.data() ); ` or `std::copy( ch_array.get(), word.begin(), word.end() );`

Comment: @VictorGubin Thanks !

Comment: @VictorGubin `std::unique_ptr` already supports dynamically allocated arrays, there's no need to reinvent it

Comment: Why not just keep using the `std::string`? It is generally much better than a dynamically allocated array.

Comment: @Galik I know it's better but I want to practice smart pointers and I was just trying new things.

Comment: @MuhammadAliKhan you could use `std::unique_ptr<std::string>` instead of `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`, that way you get the best of both worlds: `std::unique_ptr<std::string> ch_str(new std::string(word));` or `auto ch_str = std::make_unique<std::string>(word);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is self explanatory. You are passing a `std::unique_ptr` where a `char*` is expected. `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` is not implicitly convertible to `char*`. You need to call its `get()` method to obtain a `char*` pointer to its allocated memory.

Also, `strcpy()` expects and produces a null-terminated C string. But you are not doing anything to ensure that `word`'s data fits within the bounds of the specified `arraysize`.

Try this instead:

```
int arraysize{0};
std::string word;

std::cout << "Input size of array: ";
std::cin >> arraysize;
std::cin.ignore();

std::unique_ptr<char[]> ch_array(new char[arraysize+1]);
// or:
// auto ch_array = std::make_unique<char[]>(arraysize+1);

std::cout << "Input a word: ";
getline(std::cin, word);

strncpy(ch_array.get(), word.c_str(), arraysize);
// or:
// std::copy(word.begin(), word.end(), ch_array.get());
ch_array[arraysize] = '\0';
```

Alternatively, don't ask the user for the `arraysize` at all, just use the `word`'s own size instead:

```
std::string word;
size_t arraysize;

std::cout << "Input a word: ";
getline(std::cin, word);

arraysize = word.size();

std::unique_ptr<char[]> ch_array(new char[arraysize+1]);
// or:
// auto ch_array = std::make_unique<char[]>(arraysize+1);

strncpy(ch_array.get(), word.c_str(), arraysize);
// or:
// std::copy(word.begin(), word.end(), ch_array.get());
ch_array[arraysize] = '\0';
```